# VBA code to copy table data from webpage into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web, copy

I wish to copy data from a table on a webpage into Excel using VBA code but didn't get anything on the Excel sheet :(.

I have tried to put together some VBA code from different sources. Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyWebData()

Dim IE As Object

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/earnings.jhtml?tab=details&symbols=GOOG"
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim elem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set idoc = IE.document
Set elem = idoc.getElementsByClassName("layout-outer-table-width")(0).innerText

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1:A1000") = "" ' erase previous data
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1").Value = elem

End Sub
```

This is a password-protected webpage and I have logged in so I can see the webpage has been successfully pulled out by the VBA code. However, the data in the table on this webpage failed to be copied into excel - I saw nothing on the destination worksheet.

As you can see, I used code .getElementsByClassName("layout-outer-table-width") since I used Chrome's "Inspect" function to check the webpage and found that when the mouse was hovering over the statements:

```
...<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="layout-outer-table-width"> == $0

 <tbody>...</tbody>

 </table>
```

part of the webpage covering the table I need was shaded. I then coded in the class name "layout-outer-table-width". However, as I said, I didn't see anything appearing on the Excel sheet.

Any instruction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the complete HTML code for that table? If not, you need to loop through the table. In that case, you also need to declare a variable that can hold multiple elements. Also, make sure that the text is generated before you retrieve it. You can test it using `Do Until trim(var)<>vbNullString`. Also, `Set` statement is used for objects not strings. So you may want to remove that `Set` statement before `elem` variable in your code.

Comment: Hi SpaghettiCode, many thanks for your advice! I have managed to get the table with Qharr's code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after the earnings detail table you need a different selector. I am showing a css selector for that table. Your current selector (class), and index 0, is matching on a breadcrumb (nav tree). That class is also not correct for selecting the table on the page.

```
.earningsHistoryTable-Cont table
```

I cannot test this but you may also want a timed loop for table to be present

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub RetrieveInfo()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, clipboard As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/earnings.jhtml?tab=details&symbols=GOOG"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#userId").Value = "xyz"
            .querySelector("#password").Value = "123456"
            .querySelector("form").submit
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer                                'timed loop for details table to be present
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = IE.document.querySelector(".earningsHistoryTable-Cont table")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing
        If Not hTable Is Nothing Then  'use clipboard to copy paste
            clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr, thanks very much for correcting my code!! I tried to run your code but encountered "run time error 424" initially. So I removed the part of your code between "With" and "End With" and entered login details manually then your code worked as I could see the table being copied to the sheet! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have modified your code to try to get a sequence of similar tables - please see my updated code above. However, these tables copied into respective sheets are exactly the same, that is, the table for the first variable/sheet has been replicated to the other sheets which are created for different variables - the tables should be different on different sheets. What's wrong with my new code? Your advice again would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hi QHarr, thanks for your advice and sorry for the confusion - I am still new to this web. Following your advice, I have restored the original question and posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757268/vba-code-to-copy-table-from-webpage-into-excel    Again, your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: @David If only everyone responded so positively :-) I will have a look. As before, it is likely I won't be able to test the code fully.