# VBA code to copy table from webpage into Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, copy

I have modified the code to try to get a sequence of similar tables. However, these tables copied into respective sheets are exactly the same, that is, the table for the first variable/sheet has been replicated to the other sheets which are created for different variables - the tables should be different on different sheets. What's wrong with my new code? Your advice again would be very appreciated!

```
Sub CopyWebTable()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, clipboard As Object, t As Date
    Dim Var As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    For i = 1 To 3
        Var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Par").Range("B" & i + 2)

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate2 "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/earnings.jhtml?tab=details&symbols=" & Var

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            t = Timer                            'timed loop for details table to be present
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set hTable = IE.document.querySelector(".earningsHistoryTable-Cont table")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While hTable Is Nothing
            If Not hTable Is Nothing Then        'use clipboard to copy paste
                clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Var).Range("A1").PasteSpecial

            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following construct where we move the loop over vars inside the creation of the IE object and ensure hTable is always set to nothing before looping round again.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyWebTable()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, clipboard As Object, t As Date
    Dim Var As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True

        For i = 1 To 3
            Var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Par").Range("B" & i + 2)

            .Navigate2 "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/earnings.jhtml?tab=details&symbols=" & Var

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            t = Timer                            'timed loop for details table to be present
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set hTable = .document.querySelector(".earningsHistoryTable-Cont table")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While hTable Is Nothing
            If Not hTable Is Nothing Then        'use clipboard to copy paste
                clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Var).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                Set hTable = Nothing
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks again for your help, QHarr. Your code worked after a minor change.

Comment: See if you can pass authorization via xmlhttp ? https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: I found the code running slowly when copying more webpages. Not even faster than manual copy and paste. Any advice on how to make it running faster?

Comment: the main problem is I cannot test this properly and not sure others, without a proper account, can either. Look into XHR to see if there is a way to get the info via xmlhttp rather than opening a browser which is slow. Also, see if the company provides an API you can use (first choice). Otherwise, a small gain could be made from not using clipboard and instead storing table in an array and writing array out to sheet.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice to pass authorization via xmlhttp. I read the webpage you sent and put together some code at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786109/pass-authorization-via-xmlhttp      However, this code didn't work. Could you please have a look? Many thanks.